# Docker runs old container instead of new one that I'm pulling (AWS)

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, docker, containers, putty

I recently deployed a Springboot application to AWS using Docker.

I'm going crazy trying to update my image/container. I've tried deleting everything, used and unused containers, images, tags, etc. and pushing everything again.  Docker system prune, docker rm, docker rmi, using a different account too... It still runs that old version of the project.

It all indicates that there's something going on at the server level. I'm using PuTTY.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of a sequence of commands that doesn't work, and what effect you actually see?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by old container ? Is it some changes you did from some version control then didn't update on the container ?or just do docker restart **container I'd**

Comment: By old container I mean the version of my project that first time I successfully did a docker run. Then some changes were made, but they're not reflected because every time I do a docker run this old version shows up.

Comment: If hosted on some server ssh to the server then cd to your project and git pull.Try to run it again

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to unpack here, so if you can provide more information - that'd be good. But here's a likely common denominator.

If you're using any AWS service (EKS, Farget, ECS), these are just based on the docker image you provide them. So if your image isn't correctly updated, they won't update.

But the same situation will occur with `docker run` also. If you keep pointing to the same image (or the image is conceptually unchanged) then you won't have a change.

So I doubt the problem is within Docker or AWS.

**Most Likely**

1. You're not rebuilding the spring application binaries with each change
2. Your Dockerfile is pulling in the wrong binaries
3. If you are using an image hosting service, like ECR or Nexus, then you need to make sure the image name is pointing to the correct image:tag combination. If you update the image, it should be given a unique tag and then that tagged image referenced by Docker/AWS

After you build an image, you can verify that the correct binaries were copied by using `docker export <container_id> | tar -xf - <location_of_binary_in_image_filesystem>`

That will pull out the binary. Then you can run it locally to test if it's what you wanted.

You can view the entire filesystem with `docker export <container_id> | tar -tf - | less`